# Storing Hidden Values in HTML (for tooltip, error, defaults) Best Practices

Tags: jquery, html, validation, configuration, defaults

I just saw this [JQuery Metadata Plugin](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/metadata/jquery.metadata.js) by John Resig, Yehuda Katz, Jarn Zaefferer, and Paul McLanahan, in my search for [JQuery Form Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), and that's an interesting idea!

I'm wondering what general best practices are for storing things like error/validation text, tooltip text, default value text, etc.  I know you can place them into the `title="My Tooltip Message"` attribute, but that would get very messy and wouldn't be DRY if a lot of my items had the same tooltips and errors so to speak.

So is there anything wrong with storing all of that in either *hidden input fields* or *html metadata*?  Or is there a better way of just storing it all in an XML config file and getting them out via JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 supports custom attributes starting with "data-" ex: "data-origvalue" could store the original value of an input which could be used later to determine if the user changed it.

JQuery 1.4 now supports this natively using the .data() functions: http://api.jquery.com/data/

If you're not going to use JQuery, the [official best practice recommendation](http://html5.org/tools/web-apps-tracker?from=4461&to=4462) is to use something like "data-LIBRARYNAME-ATTRNAME" ex: "data-jquery-origvalue" so no two libraries will conflict. I suggest you follow this and come up with some unique for the "LIBRARYNAME" part.

Comment: Is it okay to start using HTML 5 for that, will it work cross browser?

Comment: @viatropos It'll definitely work and render fine but won't pass w3c validation if you care about that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd store tooltips in the "title" tag given that that is the supported location for it.

As for other metadata? Depends. Generally I'll store them in made-up properties on the object itself, because this is also supported. Up to personal preference though, IMHO. If I didn't do that, I'd store them in some sort of map in a secondary .js file, but that would get annoying to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You could also store all the things right in JS file - which could be on-the-demand generated by ASP.NET or PHP, so you'll edit all messages in format you like and then just output it as js array or something.